# What's the actual use of parking lot?

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

Does that have something to do with the time? Or the cars one the road? The items to be delivered? Or the lighting in environment, like that?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the parking lots in front of motels, gas stations, truck shops, etc. to sleep.

I don't remember if this was an issue when you did deliveries for other companies, but once you get your own truck and your own company, your driver needs to sleep every day.

This also becomes an issue when you start getting longer deliveries, where you can't make the trip without sleeping in the middle of it.

Comment: It's kind of horrifyingly depressing that your driver sleeps in a parking lot in a company truck.